# Rewrite 3 dashes to only one dash in url

Tags: regex, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I've got some urls looks like

```
forum/131-Call-Of-Duty-Black-Ops-2---Problemy-techniczne/107002-Call-of-duty-black-ops-2-brak-dziwieku.html
```

As you can see, there are "---" in the url. How can I rewrite them to only one "-", so the url will look like this:

```
forum/131-Call-Of-Duty-Black-Ops-2-Problemy-techniczne/107002-Call-of-duty-black-ops-2-brak-dziwieku.html
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use this rule:

```
RewriteRule ^(.*?)---(.*)$ /$1-$2 [L,R]
```

Comment: it works, but somehow it also removes forum/ from begining of url. I need to figured why.

Comment: RewriteRule ^(.*?)---(.*)$ /forum/$1-$2 [L,R] worls like charm. Thank you :)